# Is the word “Galapagos” transferable into adjective and verb to mean “outdated, fossilized” in English?

Tags: word-usage, proper-nouns

We have a word “Gala-kei-ガラ携” which is an abbreviation of “Galapagos (shortened as Gala” and “mobile phone (shortened as “Kei”) meaning outdated mobile phone as opposed to advanced smart-phones in Japanese.
We also call a person who sticks to old way of thinking “Galapagosu jin –ガラパゴス人.” Jin means people.

I heard in this site that most nouns can be used as a verb as well. For instance, an aggressive restaurant waitress retorts the patron by snapping back "Don't you 'young lady' me, smart guy," to the patron's growl,"You listen to me young lady," in the episode (http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/culture/2014/06/lunch-at-gitlitzs.html) in the New Yorker magazine I quoted in my previous post, "[What does “There she blows’” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178213/what-does-there-she-blows-mean)"

Is the word “galapagos” transferable into adjective (e.g. *galapagos mind-set*) and verb (e.g. *galapagosize*) in English to mean “outdated” or "anachronistic" in  the same way as ‘fossil’ verbalized into ‘fossilize’?

If it’s not transferable, what would it be the equivalent English word to “Garakei,” Garapagosu jin” and “Garapagostic bigotory?

Comment: The first time I have seen your name with the diamond - congratulations!

Comment: @StoneyB. My name with diamond? I don't understand. What is it?

Comment: @YoichiOishi He means the diamond ♦ next to your name.

Comment: Moderator diamond

Comment: Oh well. Thank you. I didn't notice that.

Comment: I've never seen this expression in English, but Googling shows a lot of hits on *Galapagos technology* - with specific reference to a *Japanese* "Galapagos syndrome". It could very well happen in the not-too-distant future that English will extend this borrowing and use it as freely as your language - including adjectival, adverbial, and verbal uses.

Comment: I've never seen it before (in English). Is "Galapagos" here in reference to the famed _Galapagos Islands_ of Charles Darwin fame? If so, it's an exceedingly odd usage and I hope it never takes root in English. I would agree with @mplungjan's answer of "dino-" (prefix) or "dinosaur" (adjective) being more customary in English.

Comment: @Yoichi: I think, It would be nice if you can modify the question to ask the equivalent of this in English also. (instead of just asking about Galapagos, because answers are going towards that also)

Comment: In English the Galapagos Islands do not have connotations of antiquity or obsolescence.  They are associated with evolution and new things.  I have been there, I felt no sense of age at all.  Perhaps this is why the word is not used as an adjective.  As others have said, use Dinosaur.

Comment: There might not be an acceptable verb form for whatever word you decide on: An outdated phone doesn't really "outdate" - it just *becomes outdated* because a new phone has replaced it.

Comment: It’s not entirely clear from the way you’ve worded it whether a ガラ携 is just any phone that is not a smartphone (whether outdated or not), or whether it is just any phone that is outdated and obsolete (whether a smartphone or not). If it is in fact the former, the usual English term is ***dumbphone***; if the latter, I don’t think there is a specific word.

Comment: @user568458. It should be "most nouns can be used as verbs." I was careless. Than you for pointing out it.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet. a ガラ携 refers to outdated mobile-phone, current a generation before smart phone. As I'm one of very few "Galapagosic" old man  who don't use neither ガラ携 or old-type mobile phone, I can'tell the difference well. The old, fixed home telephone suffice me.

Comment: English language Wikipedia article on Galapagos syndrome: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galápagos_syndrome

Comment: @emanen. Thank you for giving me a good  advice. I added a question about English equivalent of the Japanese palagagos compounds per your suggestion.

Comment: @mplungian. I didn't notice the Diamond mark until being told by StoneyB and you,  as it looks square in shape, and doesn't look like a diamond at all.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombus - _The rhombus is often called a diamond, after the diamonds suit in playing cards_

Comment: I don’t believe anyone has mentioned this, but I am guessing that it is the giant Galápagos tortoises, renowned for their longevity, that have given rise to this expression.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In English the word most matching your usage is

[***Dinosaur***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dinosaur)

> 1. a fossil reptile of the Mesozoic era, often reaching an enormous size.
> 2. **a person or thing that is outdated or has become obsolete because of failure to adapt to changing circumstances.**

For example

- [I love my dinosaur phone](http://birdeemag.com/i-love-my-dinosaur-phone/)

  > The real reason I haven’t upgraded my phone – even though it would be convenient, even though everyone else has, even though smartphones are really incredibly cool and aesthetically pleasing and goddamn I love fingerprinting technology ... is that I don’t really need to.
- [The Office Phone Is Not a Dinosaur.](http://www.boston.com/jobs/news/jobdoc/2014/03/the_office_phone_is_not_a_dino.html)

  > Office phones really are very much in use even if many of us also have a cell phone at work.
- [MAKING THE SWITCH: 9 SIGNS IT’S TIME TO UPGRADE YOUR PHONE](http://www.logicbuy.com/features/signs-its-time-to-upgrade-your-smartphone)

  > Some people like to have the latest and greatest technology when it comes to cell phones, but others are perfectly content to use their old phones until they go obsolete. If you're on the latter end, take a look at these 9 signs that it's time to upgrade your phone. After all, you can't use your ***'dinosaur' phone*** forever..

Other usage

- [Bitcoin Is a High-Tech Dinosaur Soon to Be Extinct](http://www.bloombergview.com/articles/2013-12-31/bitcoin-is-a-high-tech-dinosaur-soon-to-be-extinct)

  > Bitcoin is the future, they tell us; it heralds a future where private, stateless currencies will dethrone the dollar and other ***monetary dinosaurs***.
  >   Sorry, but Bitcoin isn’t the future. If anything, it’s a throwback to an earlier era, when private currencies circulated alongside government-sponsored money. I
- *I've never spent a lot of time on Java before; **I'm such a dinosaur** that my studies preceded the Java craze*

Comment: +1. I'm not sure whether a [Nokia 2140](http://nokiamuseum.com/view.php?model=2140%20Orange%205.0) is a dinosaur phone though. Perhaps it is. [I used to have one of those. Brilliant in its day.]

Comment: A colleague has one still. I get SMSs in all uppercase. I am surprised it even can access any current networks

Comment: +1 Can't really be used in verb/adjective form, but I am totally going to start using "dinosaur" around the office.

Comment: @Doc No I wont.

Comment: Creating a shortened form akin to Japanese ガラ携, my immediate thought was _dinophone_ … but then that somehow makes me think of purple Flintstone pets …

Comment: I would say 'antediluvian', which means 'before the flood'; referring to the biblical flood in the old testament. It's used as a hyperbolic way to say something is very old.

Comment: @mplungjan old phone networks linger for ever.  It was only about a decade ago that most of the world shut down 1g analog systems.  I don't know about where you live; but the 4 major US carriers are planning to continue operating their primary 2g networks for 2.5 to 6.5(?) or more years.  (2.5 is ATT pulling its plug on jan1 2017, 6.5 is VZW being ambiguous about if 2021's the soonest they may shut it down or the longest they'll keep it up - I've seen both claims but never the original statement.)

Comment: A Nokia 2140 is definitely a dinosaur.   This is a great answer - I didn't think of it, and as soon as I saw it I thought "yes!!"

Comment: A giant Galápagos tortoise sometimes seems like something from the mythical age of dinosaurs, even though of course the turtle clan are much more primitive than any dinosaur, avian or otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is *no*, I don't know of any English verb/adjective form of Galápagos - and when used as a noun, it's almost always referring to the [geographic location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gal%C3%A1pagos_Islands). But there are plenty of other adjectives we can use to describe outdated things.

If you describe your phone as **antique**, **dated**, **obsolete**, or **ancient**, it conveys the idea that your phone is old, outdated, and should be replaced with a newer model. You can also use the term **vintage**, but that implies more of a positive connotation. (The owner of a "vintage phone" might be proud of how old it is and thus refuses to upgrade.)

For a more humorous effect, you can call your phone **prehistoric** or **primordial** - which aren't meant to be taken literally, but can be used to imply the phone is *absurdly* outdated. (Similar to **dinosaur** as previously mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

As a (North) American, I have never heard of "Galapagos" being used that way, even though that may be the case in Japan.

I have a number of friends from that part of the world (Colombia, Ecuador, Peru) that have told me, "we sometimes feel that Japan is closer to us than the United States." One of those countries (Peru) elected a President of Japanese ancestry, the United States never has (so far).